# INSERT SQL not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I have a database and a table called `studuniform`, the unique column is `Record`

[studuniform table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHktR.jpg)

I also have an update page which allow user to update data, here is the code and image

[form and add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYcKp.jpg)

```
    <table width=700 border=1 rows=1 cols=4 align='center' cellpadding=4>
        <tr>
            <th width=168>Uniform</th>
            <th width=165 align='center'>T-Shirt</th>
            <th width=165 align='center'>Pant</th>
            <th align=center>Shoes</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id='tblUniform' width=700 border=1 rows=1 cols=4 align='center' cellpadding=4>";

    while($row_rsStudUni = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsStudUni)) {
        if($row_rsStudUni["IDNum"] == $ID) {
            if(!empty($row_rsStudUni["lstSizeShirt"])) {
                echo "<tr><td width=168 height=60>Size</td>
                    <td><select name='lstSizeShirt[]' id='lstSizeShirt[]' class='TxtField' style='width:162px;'>
                        <option value='0'>&nbsp;</option>
                        <option value='S' ";if($row_rsStudUni["lstSizeShirt"]=='S'){ echo 'selected';} echo ">S</option>
                        <option value='M' ";if($row_rsStudUni["lstSizeShirt"]=='M'){ echo 'selected';} echo ">M</option>
                        <option value='L' ";if($row_rsStudUni["lstSizeShirt"]=='L'){ echo 'selected';} echo ">L</option>
                        <option value='XL' ";if($row_rsStudUni["lstSizeShirt"]=='XL'){ echo 'selected';} echo ">XL</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        Others
                        <input type='text' name='txtSizeShirt[]' value='".$row_rsStudUni["txtSizeShirt"]."' class='TxtField' style='width:111px;'>
                    </td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    </table>

    <input type='button' name='btnAddSize' value='Add Size' class='Button' onClick='AddSize()'>
    <input type='button' name='btnDelRow' value='Delete Row' class='Button' onClick='delRowUniform()'>
```

I also put add button which user can add the data, using javascript

```
function AddSize()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("tblUniform");
    var rowNum = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

    var row = table.insertRow(rowNum);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    var i = rowNum-2;

    cell1.style.width = "168px";
    cell1.style.height= "60px";

    cell1.innerHTML = "Size";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<select name='lstSizeShirt[]' id='lstSizeShirt[]' class='TxtField' style='width:162px';><option value=0>&nbsp;</option><option value=S>S</option><option value=M>M</option><option value=L>L</option><option value=4>XL</option></select><br>Others&nbsp;<input type='text' name='txtSizeShirt[]' class='TxtField' style='width:111px';>";   
    cell3.innerHTML = "<select name='lstSizePant[]' class='TxtField' style='width:162px;'><option value=0>&nbsp;</option><option value=26>26</option>    <option value=28>28</option><option value=30>30</option><option value=32>32</option><option value=34>34</option><option value=36>36</option><option value=38>38</option><option value=40>40</option><option value=42>42</option></select><br>Others&nbsp;<input type='text' name='txtSizePant[]' class='TxtField' style='width:111px;'>";
    cell4.innerHTML = "<select name='lstSizeShoes[]' class='TxtField' style='width:162px;'><option value=0>&nbsp;</option><option value=6>6</option><option value=7>7</option><option value=8>8</option><option value=9>9</option><option value=10>10</option><option value=11>11</option><option value=12>12</option></select><br>Others&nbsp;<input type='text' name='txtSizeShoes[]' class='TxtField' style='width:111px;'>";
}

function delRowUniform() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tblUniform");
    var rowNum = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

    lastRow = rowNum - 1; 

    document.getElementById("tblUniform").deleteRow(lastRow);

}
```

The UPDATE SQL is working perfectly. However, when i try to insert data into `studuniform` where IDNum and Record not exists, it's not working. I've set the `$ID` variable at the beginning of the page. Here is the PHP code to update/insert data

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM studuniform WHERE IDNum='$ID'");
$row_rsStudUni = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

foreach($_POST['lstSizeShirt'] as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($_POST['lstSizeShirt'])) {
        $lstSizeShirt = $_POST['lstSizeShirt'][$key];

        $con->query("UPDATE studuniform SET lstSizeShirt='{$lstSizeShirt}' WHERE IDNum = '$ID' AND Record = '$key'");

        $con->query("INSERT INTO studuniform (Record, IDNum, lstSizeShirt) SELECT '{$key}', '{$ID}', '{$lstSizeShirt}' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studuniform WHERE IDNum = '$ID' AND Record = '$key') LIMIT 1");
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined $key variable?

Comment: No. Do i need to define $key as well? How about this `$_POST['lstSizeShirt'] as $key => $value`?

Comment: Okay. I get it. Have you tried the print out the query? Put it in phpmyadmin's MySql section and see if any error is displayed or not

Comment: Can you spot the error? Is it the SQL code?

Comment: Can you please give us your printed mysql query for reference? I need to check the data you have passed dynamically.

Comment: It worked! I tried to print out the query in phpmyadmin's MySql section as you suggested. The problem is; in the `studuniform` table, i have `No` column which is the primary key, however i didn't set the column as auto-increment. Duplicate key error. Thank you so much! Do you have any idea how to delete data when the row in the update page is deleted?

Comment: I 'm glad you have solved the problem. I am not getting you exactly in your 2nd question. What do you mean by "delete data when the row in the update page is deleted"?

Comment: Have you put any delete button in your update page?